# Can't get the LED to 'LOW'

Tags: arduino, int, switch-statement

I can't get the random LED to 'LOW' if the LDRValue is lower than 500. The code doesn't read the if statement in the case. It sets a LED to 'HIGH' and reads the value of the lightsensor, if the value is lower than 500 the LED has to go 'LOW' and then another LED has to turn 'HIGH' and over and over.

```
int randNumber;
int LDR1 = A1;
int LDR2 = A2;
int LDR3 = A3;
int LDR4 = A4;
int LDR5 = A5;
int LS = 500;
int LDRValue = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  randNumber = random(1, 6);
}

void loop() {  
switch (randNumber) {
case 1:
    digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
    LDRValue = analogRead(LDR1);
    Serial.println(LDRValue);
    if (LDRValue < LS) {
      digitalWrite(2, LOW);
    }
    break;
case 2:
    digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
    LDRValue = analogRead(LDR2);
    Serial.println(LDRValue);
    if (LDRValue < LS) {
      digitalWrite(3, LOW);
    }
    break;
case 3:
    digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
    LDRValue = analogRead(LDR3);
    Serial.println(LDRValue);
    if (LDRValue < LS) {
      digitalWrite(4, LOW);
    }
    break;
case 4:
    digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
    LDRValue = analogRead(LDR4);
    Serial.println(LDRValue);
    if (LDRValue < LS) {
      digitalWrite(5, LOW);
    }
    break;
case 5:
    digitalWrite(6, HIGH);
    LDRValue = analogRead(LDR5);
    Serial.println(LDRValue);
    if (LDRValue < LS) {
      digitalWrite(6, LOW);
    }
    break;
}
}
```

Comment: are you sure that LDRValue actually goes below 500 ever? (debugger, println output)? also consider putting the `digitalWrite(n, HIGH)` command into an `else` block.

Comment: yes i use println and it goes below 500

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your `case`statements like this:

```
case 5:    
    LDRValue = analogRead(LDR5);
    Serial.println(LDRValue);
    if (LDRValue < LS) 
    {
        digitalWrite(6, LOW);
    }
    else
    {
        digitalWrite(6, HIGH);
    }
    break;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

We want to activate an random LED, then if the LDR of that LED registers below 500 the LED needs to deactivate and another random LED needs to activate.

Comment: If this is your specification, you'll need a different approach: in an outer loop, pick a random number, activate the LED that corresponds to that number, then enter a loop for that LED, watching its LDR. As soon as it goes below 500 for the first time, set it to LOW and exit the inner loop. remember which LED you last activated, and generate more random numbers until the generated number is different from the last one.